# 2 hints appearing when TextInputLayout is focused

Tags: android, textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am having some trouble with the TextInputLayout.

When the TextInputLayout is focused, I am seeing the hint text float above the text field and also stay on the text field. Attaching images: [image]

And when I type stuff on the field, the text overlaps the hint on the text field.

[image]

This is the XML for my TextInputLayout

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="hint">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I am using the android material components library like so:

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

How do I get the hint TextInputLayout to hide when it is focused on has text on it?

Here is the complete layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.login.login.LoginFragment">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="279dp"
        android:layout_height="289dp"
        android:src="@drawable/react"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/vitrix_logo"/>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" android:contentDescription="@string/click_to_login_to_the_app"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/createNewAccount"/>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="@string/create_account"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/createNewAccount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="hint">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The base activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">


<fragment
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragment" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two `TextInputLayout` setups overlapping? Is this possibly in a `Fragment`?

Comment: Yup, I have removed all other TextInputLayout from the layout.

Comment: Is this in a `Fragment`, by chance?

Comment: Yup, its in a Fragment. Is that going to be an issue?  :,(

Comment: Nah, not just being in a `Fragment`. I would guess that you might have two overlapping `Fragment`s, though. The described behavior doesn't really seem possible with a single `TextInputLayout` setup. A quick way to test would be to set a solid background color on the `Fragment`'s layout.

Comment: I've added the complete layout. I am pretty sure I do not have overlapping fragments.

Comment: You might try the quick test I edited my comment above to suggest. If you don't see the extra hint anymore when you do that, then I would have to say that you are somehow ending up with multiple `Fragment`s.

Comment: Your right. It looks like I have an extra fragment. How would did I end up with an extra fragment, this is the first screen of the app. :(

Comment: Not sure. There are several different ways for that to happen. One common mistake is to have a `<fragment>` element in the layout, and then dynamically loading that same `Fragment` again in code. The `<fragment>` element is already causing that `Fragment` to be loaded automatically by the framework. That's just one way, though. I only mention it because it's the one I most often see. We'd need more info to be certain of what's happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193148/discussion-between-drkstr-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just loading the fragment twice.

I was loading in the Fragment once using navigation components and a second time from the main activity auto-generated boilerplate code you get when you use an Activity + Fragment template.

To solve the issue, just remove the FragmentTrancaction.replace from your main activity and let the Nav Component load up the fragment for you.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve the result you expect:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Full name">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etFullName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I tried putting the hint on the parent TextInputLayout, no luck. I am still getting the same result :(

Comment: Did you remove the hint in TextInputEditText?

Comment: Yup, ive removed the other hint.

Comment: Can you use the layout by android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout intead of com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout? Like my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout intead of com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_mobnumber_box"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_mobnumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:hint="Mobile Number" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```